# How to start studying philosophical logic?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

As I am planing to study philosophical logic, I have some important questions. For example, I wonder:

1 Should I start with the algebraic approach? Should I start with another approach? (Which one?)

2 Which types of logic should I start with? Modal logic? Paraconsistent logic? Substructural logic? Relevance logic? Hmm, there are many choices! And why should I begin with this particular one over that?

3 Having decided where to begin (supposing it is paraconsistent logic), which texts do you recommend for study? (For example, there are few books I know on paraconsistent logic.)

4 Should I post this question also on mathematics stackexchange?

For my background, I have already studied some logic. I know what a language, deduction, first order language, syntax, and semantics are. I have studied the completeness theorem of FOL, too, and many other things.

By the way, I am more interested in non-classical logic.

Comment: Seems pretty similar to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-do-i-start-studying-mathematical-logic?rq=1

Comment: use this blog: http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Comment: I would start and end with CWA Whiitaker 'Ariistotle's De Interpretatione: Contradiction and Dialectic'. For philosophy this seems enough by itself. You could look into paraconsistent logics and other forms but I see no advantage in doing so. We want to understand philosophy in the way we usually think and Aristotle's dialectic would be enough - just as long as we keep to the rules as explained by Whittaker, which among philosophers happens less often than you might imagine.

Comment: I bought this book used, "The Blackwell Guide to Philosophical Logic" (2001). I would say it is on an intermediate or advanced level. It is a survey of various logics in separate chapters, twenty chapters!  This will just give you an idea of what's out there. Frankly, I don't understand most of it. I would guess that a lot of college libraries have it.

Comment: @PeterJ thanks for this suggestion. I think you have given it before and this time I've made note of Whittaker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First book to self-learn logic, mainly to improve reading comprehension?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/first-book-to-self-learn-logic-mainly-to-improve-reading-comprehension)

Answer (score 5):

Start with some good introductory book, like :

> - John Burgess, [Philosophical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691156336) (2009).

or

> - James Garson, [Modal Logic for Philosophers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107609526) (2006).

More detailed :

> - Graham Priest, [An Introduction to Non-classical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521670268) (2nd ed 2008).